# Installation on gentoo

Tags: ros, gentoo, rosinstall, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on the latest version of gentoo and it seems there is a mismatch in the way ROS defines package dependencies. Specifically, rosinstall tries to satisfy dependencies by installing "dev-util/gtest" whereas gentoo maintains gtest at "dev-cpp/gtest". It would be very helpful if this issue is resolved soon with high priority. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30147/installation-on-gentoo/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix the problem by changing "dev-util/gtest" to "dev-cpp/gtest" in the file ros/rosdep.yaml, originally downloaded by rosinstall. It would be useful if this fix is accepted upstream.

---

Originally posted by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) with karma: 287 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0